# Combine two variables in one request using Rx

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2, rx-android

I want to combine company and workFor variables into one stream, but I don't know how. I tried to use switchMap, zip, merge and concatMapIterable but nothing worked. Or I did something wrong..

My data model:

```
 data class UserCompany(
    @field:Json(name = "user") val user: User,
    @field:Json(name = "company") val company: Company,
    @field:Json(name = "workFor") val workFor: List<Company>
)
```

And my current code:

```
    authApi.getCompany(getJwt()) //here I get data that looks like the above model
           .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
           .flatMapIterable { 
                return@flatMapIterable it.data.workFor.toMutableList().add(it.data.company) //error Type mismatch
           },

//should returns stream of company and workFor
```

How to combine two variables from one request using Rx?

Edit, better example.
Let's say we have:

```
data class Pet(val name: String)

data class PetResult(
    val myPet: Pet, //dog
    val otherPet: List<Pet> //cat, bird, cow
)
```

And i wannt to get something like this:

```
authApi.getPet() // response looks like PetResult (model above)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .subscribe(
        { petList.setSuccess(it) }, // should returns dag, cat, bird, cow
        { petList.setError(it.message) }
    )
```

So, how to merge myPet with otherPet that i get from one API request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve the above example like below:

```
    apiClient.getPet.flatMap {
        var getListResponse=it;  
        //From getListResponse you will get Result obj which contain pet and other pet list
        var pet=it.getPet()
        var petList=it.getPetList()
        petList.add(pet)
        getListResponse.setPetList=petList

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I meant something else, I added a better example

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for complicated solutions and it was so simple -.-